# gsap not scrolling in mobile/ stuck on first page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gsap

I am using this codepen on my website.

https://codepen.io/bassta/pen/kDvmC?editors=1010

Which works fine in Desktop but it is not scrolling in mobile.
 It stuck on the first page. I edit in Js but 
 still it not moving from page to another.

```
$window.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", onMouseWheel);
$document.on("keydown", onKeyDown);
```

Is there anything for mobile also to scroll?

Comment: checked it on mobile, it works `onclick` of a button, what is the issue?

Comment: Hey @Girish, I don't want onclick I just want to scroll on mobile and Desktop. I did display none to the navbar. And it is not moving from one page to another page

Comment: you can try `mobile scroll` events, for example - http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_scroll.asp.html

Comment: hey its still not working can you please add it in above codepen link... please

Comment: Have you tried touch events?. You should record the touch start and end, compare their vertical values and based on the result go to the previous / next slide. Perhaps try Hammer https://hammerjs.github.io/

Comment: Hey, @Rodrigo thanks for giving valuable time... I will look into a hammer.js